# Timeline View, Day view, Week View, Month view and add event Calendar flutter library?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am looking for **Calendar Library in Flutter** which has support for both web and mobile.

**Calendar must has all the following views**

- Schedule View
- Day View (Timeline Hourly)
- 3/5 Days view (Timeline hourly)
- Weekly View (Timeline Hourly)
- Month View (Normal Calendar)

If **Google** has open source project for same, from where code can be abstract that will also helpful.

**I have tried syncfusion-flutter-calendar but it does not support Flutter Web.**

**Following is the screenshot of type of calendar view needed**

[image: Screenshot of Google Calendar app Side Menu]

Following is all the calendar view that should look similar or same:

[image: Screenshot of all the Calendar views in Google Calendar app]

Comment: There are not many calendar library in flutter, but you can try this one: syncfusion_flutter_calendar

Comment: @Mankeomorakort Thank you. But I already tried it.

Comment: @Mankeomorakort I tried loading calendar similar to this made in JS using flutter_webview. 
Can you help me about using JS in flutter ?

Comment: What do you want to do with JS?

Comment: @Mankeomorakort load JS calendar

Comment: Requests for libraries (and other resources like tutorials) are off-topic here.

Comment: https://fluttergems.dev/packages/calendar_view/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_week_view if anyone is looking for a day/week views Or to get an idea of how to build them by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It is an option

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/getting-started but it is paid